# Is Anything Off-Limits to Deadpool?

Tags: deadpool

I have been a humongous fan of Deadpool for many years. I own the PS3 game, read as much of the comics and graphic novels as I can, heck, I've even recently started collecting some pretty neat Deadpool shirts. However, I have always wondered: does Deadpool find anything sacred or too appalling to make a humorous joke out of, or is pretty much everything fair game? Just curious.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, Deadpool isn't a fan of killing children, as we see in Uncanny X-Men after Fantomex kills a (young) clone of Apocalypse

[image]

[image]